# My site is loading slow and hanging due the livereload process being added into my index.hml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, server

I keep seeing this line of code being added dynamically into my index.html either from Grunt tasks or the server is being adding it in Heroku.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<script src="' + (location.protocol || 'http:') + '//' + (location.hostname || 'localhost') + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')</script>
```

How can I prevent adding this script into my site... It really makes my site goes slow and I can see the network of its request pending most of the time.

I am using Heroku for deploying my AngularJS App with having a Procfile as:

```
web: npm start
```

I would appreciate alot if someone could explain me how do I get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check first what the `npm start` is calling, probably something like `grunt serve` or similar. Then hunt that grunt task down and check if it's setup to support `dev` and `prod` modes, so `livereload` only gets included while developing. If no support for different modes / env, then you could just disable `livereload` altogether, for instance, with `connect` grunt task, it would be something like:

```
{
  main: {
    options: {
      port: process.env.DEV_PORT || 9002,
      base: '.',
      livereload: true
    }
  },
  (...)
}
```

So you would just set `livereload` to `false`.

Without knowing your grunt file and configuration, it's hard to give you any more details.

Comment: I did set livereload to false and I still see the livereload request on the broweser console line....

I will show you a gist of my Gruntfile  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/973f085982a7da30e3b0

Comment: well npm start I guess is calling grunt serve as in my package.json I have this: "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test",
    "start": "grunt serve",
    "dist": "grunt serve:dist",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }

Comment: According to your `Gruntfile`, you should be able to run `grunt serve dist` to run in production mode, so no livereload there